# Redemption Logon to MAPI / Exchange Server takes forever

Tags: outlook-redemption

I use Redemption DLL to get Mails from a lot of Mailboxes from the local Exchange Servers. All Mailboxes are connected on the Default MAPI Profile, Outlook is open. Switching from one Mailbox to the other in Outlook does not give any error, Sending and Receiving Mails with Outlook also seems fine.

Since some weeks my VBS Scripts using Redemption DLL fail most of the time with the .Logon Statement for the RDO Session. The last Change on the Scripts was 27.07.2022, so I suspect, something in the timing with Exchange Server 2016 has been changed by Patches.

I ran 2 Scripts each every 5 Minutes on the Server. I disabled these tasks and tested the scripts manually every 10 to 20 Minutes, because I first suspected a throttling issue. But the same, Sometimes the RDOSession.Logon works, mostly it fails.

I checked the Eventlogs of the 3 Exchange 2016 Servers for related entries but did not find any.

How can I get the exact Error when calling RDOSession.Logon simply dies not hand back the control to my script?

Comment: What is the Exchange Server version? It it on-prem or Office 365?

Comment: On Premise. Exchange 2016, CU23, Latest Patches from November.

Comment: Does the server use Basic or OAuth? If the call to Logon seems to hang, most likely that means a login prompt is shown, but if the code is running under a service, there is no user to deal with that prompt.

Comment: Not sure, what you mean with "Basic or OAuth". 
The Exchange Server is on Premise in the local Network.
On the Station where the Script runs there is a User with Access to all Mailboxes logged on. 
Outlook is open and I can send and receive Mails successfully.
Then I run my Script either from the Commandline with cscript or with wscript or I run it in debug Mode in Adersofts VBS Editor. 
When the error occurs, the Script is processing the "RDOSession.Logon" Line in the very beginning of the Script. 
There is no dialog being displayed or any error. It simply never finishes.

Comment: I checked the Mail Profile in Outlook, it is a normal Profile for a local Exchange Server with no offline cache. Within "more" - "security" there is set "Encrypt data between outlook and exchange" and not set "always prompt for login" (both translated by me, because the outlook is german. Both scripts were running fine since 2019, last change in the VBS Scripts was 2022 (changed a log directory). Normally the scripts run from a windows task but with the logged on user, for debug purposes I call them interactively or run them step by step in Adersofts VBS Editor.

Comment: Yesterday I installed the actual redemption on the Station 6.4.0.6234, before there was 6.2.0.6122. Is there any possibility to debug this Logon Statement? @DmitryStreblechenko

Comment: Please send an email to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.

Comment: Thx, you have got mail from me. @DmitryStreblechenko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Problem: The Outlook Profile Settings on the affected computer were defect.
Outlook itself did not care about this and opened fine everytime, also I was able to send and receive messages and lookup/change the connected calendars.
Calling the Account settings from within Outlook also worked fine and fast, but:
Calling the "E-Mail (32-bit)" from Control panel showed exactly the behaviour as did my scripts.
After around 20 tries (every try added a task to Taskmanager), the Profile manager opened, I deleted the Outlook Profile, restarted the Computer, created a new Profile.
Problem gone, the Scripts are running fine since then.
Massive Thanks to @DmitryStreblechenko for helping in debugging this.